# How Can I Achieve the vertical align of text in table tag without bootstrap

Tags: html, css

```
Project Information: Dummy Project
Cost:                200
Author:              Dummy Person
```

I want to align my text somewhat I like above using CSS in table tag only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default table tag in HTML provides this functionality. See code below for reference:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Project Information:</td>
    <td>Dummy Project</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cost:</td>
    <td>200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Author:</td>
    <td>Dummy Person</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```